# XDocument unable to digest url in header if encountered twice

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am consuming an xml response from a government gateway which contains a url in its root node twice (being firstly xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope" and also xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope")

XDocument will only parse this if I pull out the second one (the xmlns one) from the node.

Is there some way I can prepare XDocument to digest this repeated URL without having to manipulate the incoming xml in any way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that there is a repeated URL, but that the XML you are receiving from the gateway is not using the xsi:schemaLocation attribute correctly.  The attribute should contain pairs of whitespace separated URIs, where each pair gives the XML processor a hint about where to find the XML schema corresponding to a namespace.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaLocation for an explanation of schemaLocation.

If you have to strip out something, make it the xsi:schemaLocation attribute.

If you are validating the received XML against a schema then you will have to take steps to provide the location of the schema document, for instance populating an XmlSchemaSet and passing it to the [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.extensions.validate.aspx) extension method.

Comment: Thanks for the steer.
Following what you said, I think the xsi:schemaLocation attribute might actually be right, as when I look at the whole node (shown below) it seems to do the whitespace/hint thing.

wondering to strip out xsi as previously said.

<GovTalkMessage xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:gt="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">